# Polymer set paper-input font family

Tags: css, fonts, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

How do I set a different font-family for `paper-input`. When I inspect the element in chrome it seems to get the style from many classes. Not sure which one to override, also what does `-0` mean in a class.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paper Input's styling documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#styling) delegates to its bundled [Paper Input Container's styling documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container#styling), but it still doesn't provide a way to overwrite the font styling.

Fortunately, you can see which fonts it uses on [paper-input-container.html source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input-container.html) and overwrite the global Material Design Typography at [paper-styles/typography.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/typography.html), but I think it's not encouraged to do so, hence they didn't brought it as a customizable style.

The corresponding style for the screenshot you took is the following:

**[paper-input-container.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input-container.html)**:

```
  .input-content ::content input,
  .input-content ::content textarea,
  .input-content ::content iron-autogrow-textarea,
  .input-content ::content .paper-input-input {
    position: relative; /* to make a stacking context */
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: var(--paper-input-container-input-color, --primary-text-color);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    text-align: inherit;
    @apply(--paper-font-subhead);
    @apply(--paper-input-container-input);
  }
```

**[paper-styles/typography.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/typography.html)**:

```
--paper-font-common-base: {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* [...] */

--paper-font-subhead: {
  @apply(--paper-font-common-base);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
};
```

Anyway, the `-0` prefix is just an index. If you have two polymer elements of the same type, it'll place a `-0` prefix on the first one and a `-1` prefix on the second one. I'm not sure, but I guess that they have been translated into the CSS selector by using [updateStyles](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#Polymer.Base:method-updateStyles), since you can customize each one separately through JavaScript, so it helps to namespace each element individually while translating `:root` and `::content` keywords.

So, if you want to overwrite this specific element, I'd tell you to use the `-0` prefix, otherwise utilize a more generic class or element to properly select in a general way.

Comment: Thanks for the details.